# why is my Cloundfoundry application showing JSP files as source, not rendered?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have created a cloundfoundry app using Spring.  However, my jsp files are being rendered as pure text (as if Tomcat is not executing the source code).   The browser shows the source when requesting a particular URL.

File structure

```
webapps
 -jsp
 -javascripts
 -css
 -WEB-INF
```

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Handles Spring requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Honesty</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Honesty</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

spring config:

```
<!-- Turns on support for mapping requests to Spring MVC @Controller methods
     Also registers default Formatters and Validators for use across all @Controllers -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Thanks for any insight you can provide.  Its as if Tomcat is not serving the request as the JSP source is showing, not a JSP rendered page.

The response headers show nginx as the server:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Mon, 30 Jul 2012 03:58:16 GMT
ETag:W/"611-1343620259000"
Keep-Alive:timeout=20
Server:nginx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was my servlet mapping of "/*".  switched to just "/" and now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Spring MVC? I suppose you are putting the JSP in some resource directory which can be accessed. Would like to see your spring configuration file and your project structure.